# How to filter and include children using Z.EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

The query below is using Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6 to filter children. Its filtering and including the `AssetXref` entity correctly however the result is not able to include `Child.Parent` entity relationship

```
   var result = await _repository.GetQuery<Assets>()
                      .IncludeFilter(x => x.AssetsXRef
                                        .Where(y => y.Child.Perent.ParentID == parentID)
                                        .Select(y => y.Child.Perent)
                                    )
                     .Where(x => x.Active == true)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

I have also tried

```
   var result = await _repository.GetQuery<Assets>()
                      .IncludeFilter(x => x.AssetsXRef
                                        .Where(y => y.Child.Perent.ParentID == parentID)                                        
                                    )
                     .Include(x=>x.AssetsXRef.Select(y=>y.Child.Parent))
                     .Where(x => x.Active == true)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IncludeFilter` is not compatible with `Include`. You need to use `IncludeFilter` all the way even if there is no filter

In addition, you need to always use the full parent filter on child

Here is an example:

```
var result = await _repository.GetQuery<Assets>()
                     .IncludeFilter(x => x.AssetsXRef.Where(y => y.Child.Perent.ParentID == parentID))
                     // Might be SelectMany
                     .IncludeFilter(x => x.AssetsXRef.Where(y => y.Child.Perent.ParentID == parentID).Select(y=>y.Child.Parent))
                     .Where(x => x.Active == true)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If you wish we help you, just report the issue here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues with an online example/runnable project. We will be happy to assist you. You might only miss an IncludeFilter somewhere